# Why is dpm.wipeData() taking ~2 minutes to complete?

Tags: android, device-policy-manager

I'm using dpm.wipeData(0) to wipe data, but this function takes around 2 minutes to do the wipe. [Here is a log of the wipeData(0)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hnbxd3b86cljsgf/log.txt?dl=0). Why? Can it be improved?

Comment: Where in that log is wipeData? I see some battery stuff, lots of wifi stuff, and some audio, and system logs. Based on that log, I very much doubt the device was wiped.

How did you even get a log of wipeData? It reboots the phone, then does the wipe while the phone is booting.

Answer (score 2):

`wipeData()` is doing a factory reset of the device, similarly to what can be done in `Settings > Backup & reset > Backup my data`. This process is very long too.

A faster factory reset can be done with fastboot (bootloader command from USB) but you probably don't want to use that:

```
fastboot erase userdata
fastboot erase cache
fastboot reboot
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Almo Actually it does answer the question. It gives the reason for why wipe data takes time, and provides an alternative which is faster.

Comment: @iheanyi when I hit that button, the answer just said "2 minutes is fast for a factory reset." That doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Almo gotcha. I should have checked the dates on your comment and the answer edits.

Answer (score 0):

A few points to answer your question:

1) Why is it taking 2 minutes to complete? Because you are wiping a device, that takes time. The OS needs to wipe all user data and reboot, which takes a little time (2 minutes does not sound like too much to me).

2) Why `dpm.wipeData(`**0**`)`? What is the '0' flag supposed to do? [Shouldn't it be 1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#WIPE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)?

All in all, why do you think this should take less than 2 minutes?